# What are some codes available for Dynamical Mean Field Theory (DMFT)?

Tags: software, electronic-structure, one-topic-per-answer, condensed-matter, dynamical-mean-field-theory

One particularly field of matter modeling is that of [strongly correlated materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_correlated_material), heavy-fermion compounds with partially filled ***4f*** or ***5f*** orbitals. In brief, these are materials whose complex electronic structures cannot be appropriately described in terms of non-interacting entities. Here, DFT breaks down in this sense.

On the site, other questions have focused on methods like Density Functional Theory (DFT), Molecular Dynamics and recently Quantum Monte Carlo (QMC). For these methods, lists of [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum_chemistry_and_solid-state_physics_software) or [QMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_for_Monte_Carlo_molecular_modeling) software wiki pages are available. However, there is none for DMFT.

I know some DFT codes have DMFT implemented (e.g. [abinit](https://docs.abinit.org/topics/DMFT/)), but are those the main ones used?

What are the most popular DMFT codes used to model strongly correlated materials?

To get the ball rolling, I found **DMFTwDFT** which can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/DMFTwDFT-project/DMFTwDFT) and the corresponding arxiv paper is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.00068).

Comment: Does Garnet Chan's code called "[potato](https://github.com/gkc1000/potato/blob/master/dmft.py)" count?

Comment: Seems legit! Would you like to post an answer with some details about potato?

Comment: I'd never heard of it until I googled to answer your question. I thought PySCF had DMFT but it looks like it doesn't?  Seems Carlos Jiménez is the largest contributor on GitHub to Potato, so perhaps you can get him to answer!

Answer (score 10):

### eDMFT

Link to website: [eDMFT](http://hauleweb.rutgers.edu/tutorials/index.html)

Developer: Kristjan Haule at Rutgers University

Main features from their [website](http://hauleweb.rutgers.edu/tutorials/whatis/whatis.html#XHaule_prb10):

1. DFT+DMFT derived from the stationary Luttinger-Ward functional.
2. Local correlated orbitals: real space (rather the usual choice of Wannier space).
3. Exact double counting for DFT+DMFT from this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.115.196403).
4. Impurity solvers: continuous time quantum Monte Carlo, non-crossing, and one-crossing approximations.
5. Can calculate free energies and forces.
6. The DFT part is obtained from an interface to [Wien2K](http://www.wien2k.at).

Answer (score 9):

**DCore**: integrated **D**MFT software for **Cor**related **e**lectrons

DCore is aimed at model calculations and ab-initio calculations by the dynamical mean-field theory (DMFT). This package consists of programs with text-based and hdf5-based interface. These programs enable users to perform DMFT calculations and analyze results without writing computer code.

Website:https://issp-center-dev.github.io/DCore/master/contents.html

Several examples:

[image: Several examples have been]

**TRIQS**: **T**oolbox for **R**esearch on **I**nteracting **Q**uantum **S**ystems

Based on the TRIQS toolkit, several full-fledged applications are also available. They allow for example to solve a generic quantum impurity model or to run a complete DFT+DMFT calculation.

Developed in a collaboration between IPhT Saclay and Ecole Polytechnique since 2005, the TRIQS library and applications have allowed us to address questions as diverse as:

1. Momentum-selective aspects on cuprate superconductors (with various cluster DMFT methods)
2. Degree of correlation in iron-based superconductors (within an DFT+DMFT approach)
3. Fermionic Mott transition and exploration of Sarma phase in cold-atoms

website:https://triqs.github.io/triqs/latest/index.html

Comment: I think you should add the second program as a separate answer. This allows users to vote on a single post for each program rather than up/downvoting a post because of one of the multiple programs in it.

Comment: Next time maybe suggest the second software in a comment rather than writing a full answer about it. Otherwise for some one-topic-per-answer questions, I could have answered 10 times, leaving nothing for others!

Answer (score 7):

## Questaal

- Questaal is a first-principles DFT solver based on the LMTO basis (different from Wien2k answered by @ProfM), which is interfaced with the Continuous-Time Quantum Monte Carlo solver, developed by K. Haule and coworkers, for DMFT.
- Website: https://www.questaal.org/about/questaal/
- Description from official website:

> When localized electronic orbitals (d- or f- type) participate in the states near the Fermi level, the effect of electronic correlation can not be included as a small perturbation (RPA) and more accurate methods have to be invoked. The Questaal code has been interfaced with the Continuous-Time Quantum Monte Carlo solver developed by K. Haule and coworkers. This couples the QSGW description of the lattice with state-of-the-art Dynamical Mean Field Theory approaches. This code requires that Haule’s CTQMC be installed. The interface to that code is `lmfdmft`.